# Where is the License file location for Identity Server in Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: identity-server

I installed Sitecore 9.1 and noticed the new Identity Server site in IIS. My license is expired now. Where can i find the license file to replace for Identity Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.1 license file for `Identity Server` is kept in

> `sitecoreruntime\license.xml`

Just replace the file with your license and restart the app.